# Why does my d3.js image appear in the wrong place?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been designing a gantt chart. The javascript files are located within the html body:

```
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="arrow">Areas of Expertise</h1>
      <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.mentful.com/gantt-chart-d3v2.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/gantt.js"></script>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

However, when I look at the source, the svg file is located outside of the `section` tags:

```
<body>
  <section>...</section>
  <script>...</script>
  <svg class="chart" width="777" height="827">...</svg>
</body>
```

I want my chart to take on the properties of the container it's in. It doesn't seem to be doing that. Here is a working example of my chart in action: http://jsbin.com/pigudeyovi/2/edit?html,output

Why is the .svg outside of the `section` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the code is not significant in deciding where its output appears -- D3 requires you to specify explicitly where to add any new elements to the DOM.

In this case, the output will always appear immediately below the `body` element. This is hard-coded in the Gantt chart library source code and not configurable by the user. To change that you either need to change the source code of the library or move the DOM element yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The gnatt-chart plugin is appending the SVG to the `body`.

https://github.com/dk8996/Gantt-Chart/blob/master/gantt-chart-d3.js#L75

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to get stuck in to that plugin. Would it be as simple as changing the `body` on line 75 to `section`?

Comment: @Stacey yes that would work, you can use any selector.